# Error on authentication with ADFS server

Tags: soap, adfs2.0

Has anyone come across the following error response when authenticating the user against the ADFS server.
I am using a java SOAP webservice call to authenticate against the ADFS server.
I have used the adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed for authentication .

The problem is the end customer is not able to get the error log generated from the ADFS server

http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault2014-10-28T02:21:52.926Z2014-10-28T02:26:52.926Zs:Receivera:InternalServiceFault**The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs**.

Any insights or help would be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got the root cause. Basically, the issue was with the manner the username was send to ADFS for authentication .The ADFS was configured to authenticate the user with domain name appended before the user name